# counting rows in select clause with DB2

Tags: sql, zend-framework, select, db2

I would like to query a DB2 table and get all the results of a query in addition to all of the rows returned by the select statement in a separate column.

E.g., if the table contains columns 'id' and 'user_id', assuming 100 rows, the result of the query would appear in this format: (id) | (user_id) | 100.

I do not wish to use a 'group by' clause in the query. (Just in case you are confused about what i am asking) Also, I could not find an example here: http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/cookbook/DB2V97CK.PDF.

Also, if there is a more efficient way of getting both these results (values + count), I would welcome any ideas. My environment uses zend framework 1.x, which does not have an ODBC adapter for DB2. (See issue http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-905.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for, then the answer should be

```
select t.*, g.tally
  from mytable t,
       (select count(*) as tally
          from mytable
       ) as g;
```

If this is not what you want, then please give an actual example of desired output, supposing there are 3 to 5 records, so that we can see exactly what you want.

Comment: this is what i was looking for in terms of result set; thanks for the answer. however, i was hoping for a more efficient solution that uses an analytic function, rather than performing 2 selects.

Comment: What gives you the impression a OLAP function is doing anything less under the covers?  This is portable. I will provide a 2nd method which I prefer. For anything else, you would have to indicate which DB2 platform you are using - i, LUW, or z/OS.

Answer (score 0):

You would use window/analytic functions for this:

```
select t.*, count(*) over() as NumRows
from table t;
```

This will work for whatever kind of query you have.

Comment: tried it and got this error - it seems that it's complaining about the 'over()':
Message: [SQL0104] Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token (.  Token ( is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is , FROM INTO.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point.